# Karma Jasmine Test Angular 2 Chrome grey screen

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

So I am doing a simple unit test with karma/jasmine. I am using webpack 2.

```
//Running it.
"test": "karma start --singleRun true --browsers Chrome",

//packages
"jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
"karma": "^1.1.1",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^1.0.1",
"karma-coverage": "^1.1.0",
"karma-htmlfile-reporter": "^0.3.4",
"karma-ie-launcher": "^1.0.0",
"karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
"karma-nyan-reporter": "^0.2.4",
"karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
"karma-remap-coverage": "^0.1.2",
"karma-safari-launcher": "^1.0.0",
"karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
"karma-sourcemap-writer": "^0.1.2",
"karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.26",
"karma-webpack": "^1.8.0",
```

So when I run the test, Chrome launches, but it shows up with a grey screen.

The test is a simple test

```
import { NgRedux } from 'ng2-redux';
import { BlogPostActions } from './blog-post.actions';

class MockRedux extends NgRedux<any> {
  constructor() {
    super(undefined);
  }
  public dispatch = () => undefined;
};

describe('Login Actions Creators', () => {
  let actions: BlogPostActions;
  let mockRedux: NgRedux<any>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    mockRedux = new MockRedux();
    actions = new BlogPostActions(mockRedux);
  });

  it('should dispatch validate action', () => {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });

});
```

Anyone have any ideas as to what could be causing this? It is driving me crazy! Let me know if there is any more information that you need! There are no errors in the command line.

[image: Chrome issue]

Comment: Are there errors in the browser console? It looks like Chrome died. :'(

Comment: No, can't even open the chrome console!

Answer (score 0):

The versions that I am using are not working when the terminal, whether it be codes terminal or git bash, is ran as an admin. Removing that, fixed the issue.